# JPQL join entity field value IS NULL

Tags: java, sql, jpa, hql, jpql

I got some problems with my JPA mapping.
I wrote that query:

```
String str = "
    SELECT alrt.* 
    FROM 
        REACTION.ALERT alrt, REACTION.INVESTIGATION inv,  
        REACTION.CLASSIFICATION_TYPE clst, REACTION.FRAUD_TYPE frt,  
        REACTION.TRANS trns, REACTION.CARD crd  
    WHERE
        alrt.ISS_INST IN(1111) AND  
        alrt.MODULE_TYPE = 1 AND
        0 < (SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM REACTION.INVESTIGATION WHERE REACTION.INVESTIGATION.ALERT_ID = alrt.ID) AND 
        inv.CLASSIFICATION_TYPE_ID IS NOT NULL AND 
        clst.CLASSIFICATION_TYPE = 2 AND 
        alrt.REMINDER_USER_LOGIN = 'a' OR alrt.REMINDER_USER_LOGIN IS NULL AND  
        alrt.ID = inv.ALERT_ID AND  
        alrt.TRANSACTION_ID = trns.ID(+) AND inv.CLASSIFICATION_TYPE_ID =  
        clst.ID AND inv.FRAUD_TYPE_ID = frt.ID(+) AND trns.HPAN = crd.HPAN(+)"

Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(str, Alert.class);
```

so i recieved List entities as result.
All looks well, but only field "transaction" in Alerts entity is null(alert.getTransaction() returned null), but in my db its has value-"61".

This is how transaction value presents im my Alerts class:

```
Table(name = "ALERT", schema = "REACTION")
@Entity(name = "Alert")
public class Alert extends AbstractBaseEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9007994864788693025L;

    @Digits(fraction = 0, integer = 15)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ALERT_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "ALERT_SEQ", sequenceName = "ALERT_SEQ", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 100)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name = "TRANSACTION_ID")
    private Transaction transaction;
....
```

This is id field from Transaction entity:

```
@Entity(name = "Transaction")
@Table(name = "TRANS", schema = "REACTION")
public class Transaction extends AbstractTransaction {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1110243741971153313L;

    @Digits(fraction = 0, integer = 15)
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "TRANS_SEQ", sequenceName = "TRANS_SEQ", allocationSize = 1000)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "TRANS_SEQ")
    private Long id;
...
```

I thought it was cause i had "fetch = FetchType.LAZY" on transaction field. But fetch = FetchType.EAGER didnt solve my problem. Maybe someone can help me?

**UPDATE1:**
**try to write on JPQL, but problem still the same:**

```
SELECT alrt
FROM Investigation inv 
    JOIN inv.classificationTypeEntity clst 
    LEFT JOIN inv.fraudType frt 
    JOIN inv.alert alrt 
    LEFT JOIN alrt.transaction trns 
    LEFT JOIN trns.card crd 
WHERE 
    alrt.issinst IN(:institutions) AND 
    alrt.module = :module AND 0 < (SELECT COUNT(inv1) FROM Investigation inv1 WHERE  inv1.alert = alrt) AND 
    inv.classificationTypeEntity IS NOT NULL AND 
    clst.classificationType = :clstype AND 
   (alrt.reminderUserLogin =  :userLogin OR alrt.reminderUserLogin IS NULL);

Query query = entityManager.createQuery(str)
                    .setParameter("institutions",institutions)
                    .setParameter("module",moduleType)
                    .setParameter("clstype",ClassificationType.POSTPONED)
                    .setParameter("userLogin", userLogin);

List<Alert> resultList = query.getResultList();
for (Alert alert : resultList) {
    log.warn("ALERT TRANSACTION ID " + alert.Id());   ///returned ID
    log.warn("ALERT TRANSACTION ID " + alert.getTransaction());   ///returned NULL, WHY?(must return TRANSACTION ENTITY WITH ID=61)
    ..
}
```

Comment: how do you expect an SQL query handler to know how to populate some "related object" when the datastore has a simple numeric value? JPQL queries are what ought to be used in such situations because they are for objects.

Comment: i try to write that query on JPQL, but got the same result.Update my question. Maybe now you can help me

Comment: and the 1-1 field is being FETCHed? (i.e marked as that). The JPA impl is? The transaction boundaries are where? when you access the field is the txn still active? and what appears in the log when you do that?

Comment: update my question, maybe that clears my situation. (Spring handles all my transactions)